# How to add a model validation for string [3 .. 4] characters

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, validation

I am working this API https://developer-eu.elavon.com/docs/opayo/spec/api-reference-0#operation/createCi.

In this link, they said

```
cardholderName
required
string <= 45 characters
The name of the card holder

cardNumber
required
string <= 16 characters
The number of the card

expiryDate
required
string 4 characters
The expiry date of the card in MMYY format

securityCode
required
string [ 3 .. 4 ] characters
The card security code, also known as CV2, CVV, or CVC. This is used in CV2 checks.
```

I added for string length validation as

```
[Required]
[StringLength(45)]
public string CardholderName { get; set; }
```

In this API, they validate `securityCode` is a requiredstring [ 3 .. 4 ] characters for a POST request.

How to add a validation for
`securityCode required string [ 3 .. 4 ] characters`?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "add validation for this"?

Comment: I have added more. please check

Comment: `StringLengthAttribute` can specify a min and a max.

Comment: `[RegularExpression("^(0[1-9])|(1[0-2])2[0-9]$")]` - we accept any month in year [20]`20..29`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using *regular expressions*, e.g.

```
 [RegularExpression("^(0[1-9])|(1[0-2])2[1-9]$")] 
 public string ExpireDate {get; set;}
```

Here we accept any month in `01..12` range for any year in `21..29` range. Same for security code:

```
 [RegularExpression("^[0-9]{3,4}$")]
 public string SecurityCode {get; set;}
```

Here we accept `3` or `4` digits

Comment: Thank you. Is there any specific validator for string[x..y] characters like [StringLength(x)] ? Becasue I need to validate more like this."
`browserAcceptHeader
required
string [ 1 .. 2048 ] characters
Exact content of the HTTP accept headers as sent to the 3DS Requestor from the Cardholder's browser.`

Comment: @hanushic: you can use `^.{x,y}$` pattern: `.` stands for any symbol in regular expression; e.g.  `[RegularExpression("^.{1,2048}$")]`